# What's the representation of a linear map from one matrix space to another matrix space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Note that $e_{i},e^{\prime}_{i}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}$ and $E_{i},E^{\prime}_{i}\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ for $i=1,2,\dots, d$ in my problem.

It's easy to represent a linear map from $\operatorname{span}\{e_{i}:i=1,2,\dots,d\}\subseteq\mathbb{F}^{n}$ to $\operatorname{span}\{e^{\prime}_{i}:i=1,2,\dots,d\}\subseteq\mathbb{F}^{n}$ by a matrix $A\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ satisfying
$$
Ae_{i}=e^{\prime}_{i} \text{ for each } i,
$$

What does the representation of linear maps from $\operatorname{span}\{E_{i}:i=1,2,\dots,d\}\subseteq \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ to $\operatorname{span}\{E^{\prime}_{i}:i=1,2,\dots,d\}\subseteq \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ look like? In other words, if we have a linear map $T$ s.t. $T(E_{i})=E^{\prime}_{i}$ for each $i$, then what form could we use to represent $T$ in?

---

I think matrix tuples could work, but I am not sure of any details. I would appreciate it so much if you could show me some concrete examples. Thank you!

Comment: just note that each $E_i$ is a vector in a finite dimensional space, therefore $T$ can be represented by a $\mathbb{F}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on writing the matrices as square grids of numbers, then there is no simple way to represent such a linear map. Index notation can handle the relevant operations, but that's a whole new thing to learn, and I'm not sure it's worth it for you if all you want with it is to solve this one problem. Besides, it doesn't make it easier to type out the components of such a transformation. A "matrix of matrices" might also be a solution, but I haven't looked deeply into how to make it work out with standard matrix multiplication.

If you take each column of your matrices and stack them on top of one another to get one long column, then you're back in familiar territory, and a linear map is simply an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix.